# How can I remove (set to null) a registered singleton type in DryIoC?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dryioc

I have a requirement to completely delete an instance that is already resolved by DryIoC container (but not unregister the type). I don't know if this is possible?

If I don't use any IoC container and just declare singletons myself I of course can reset it to null easily whenever I want.

e.g:

```
 var instance = DryIocContainer.Resolve<SomeType>();//a singleton
 //All next times calling Resolve<> will return just that singleton instance.
 //But if that is cleared, the next time calling Resolve<> should create 
 //a completely new instance (like as the first time it was called).
```

The scenario here is after user logging off my app, I want to clear all resolved singletons so that if the user logging back using another account (or even with that same account), the data will be refreshed correctly. Currently without being able to clear those singletons, I have to reset all properties manually myself - which I think should just be the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
container = container.WithoutSingletonsAndCache();
```

Here is the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/KindsOfChildContainer#markdown-header-without-singletons).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really I did not have much time to dig into the doc.

Comment: I think it should some more overload to such as remove just singletons of some Type (or excluding some Types from being removed), it would be a real use case.

Comment: Simply put, it is hard to remove specific singletons and still keep a container consistent.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if this is possible?

No, this isn't really possible. Although Dadhi pointed to the `WithoutSingletonsAndCache` method, this effectively builds up a new container with a new set of instances. Although this allows you to replace your particular singleton, it also means that all other singleton registrations will be cleared and you lose the promise of there being only one instance of a particular type. In other words, in able to do this, the container has broken its promise around singletons. This effectively leads to a [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html). You will have closely analyse whether or not this will be a problem or not.

> If I don't use any IoC container and just declare singletons myself I of course can reset it to null easily whenever I want.

This is not true. Even without a container, you can't simply replace a singleton. A simple example is when this singleton to be replaced is a dependency of another singleton. Unless you replace that singleton (and all its singleton consumers up the chain), this original instance is captured within its consumer and will the consumer will keep referencing the original instance, even though you try to replace it. This is a form of the [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) problem.

The only true way to solve this problem, and solve it locally for this instance only, is to create a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for the abstraction of that Singleton. This proxy can wrap that dependency and you can allow it to be changed later on. This allows you to at any moment in time replace the dependency.

How to implement this, does highly depend on your particular needs, but here's an example:

```
public interface ISomeType
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class SomeTypeImpl : ISomeType { ... }

public class SomeTypeProxy : ISomeType
{
    public ISomeType Dependency { get; set; }

    public SomeTypeProxy(ISomeType dependency) {
        this.Dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() => this.Dependency.SomeMethod();
}
```

Without a DI container, you can use this as follows:

```
var proxy = new SomeTypeProxy(new SomeTypeImpl());

// later on
proxy.Dependency = new OtherTypeImpl();
```

Another option is to let the Proxy wrap a `Func<T>` delegate, which allows you to move this logic to the delegate:

```
ISomeType dependency = new SomeTypeImpl();

var proxy = new SomeTypeProxy(() => dependency);

// later on
dependency = new OtherTypeImpl();
```

> The scenario here is after user logging off my app, I want to clear all resolved singletons so that if the user logging back using another account

In your particular case, you are actually describing clearing the complete application. Your scenario sounds similar to restrarting the application. This is probably something that `WithoutSingletonsAndCache` works good at, because you wish to reset *all* singletons.

The same however can be achieved with just creating a new container with all its registrations. Your application will already have some sort of `CreateContainer` class, and it should be a matter of calling that `CreateContainer` method again.

Of course this method only works when your dealing with an application at only handles one user, instead of having a web application that runs requests for many users concurrently.

Comment: > "this effectively builds up a new container with a new set of registrations."
It is may be a bit misleading, because underlying Registry is immutable. New container will just get a pointer to the registry of the old container, but the further changes will be isolated for both containers. Additionally, whatever is put into the registry is validated as far as possible, so you'll get validated and persistent registrations, but will drop cache and singletons.